# catalina.out daily rolling in Tomcat9

Tags: logging, tomcat9, rollingfileappender, catalina.out

I have a default tomcat 9.0.37 installation. The catalina.out file in the server logs does not roll on a daily basis due to which its size has grown to several GBs.

However I observed that a file with the name pattern **catalina.yyyy-mm-dd.log** keeps generating but does not contain the complete logs for that day.

I already tried the following approaches as suggested in some blogs but all in vain.

#### 1. Logrotate

Created a file with the name **tomcat** and pasted the following code in it.

```
/home/tomcat/servers/tomcat/logs/catalina.out {
daily
rotate 30
missingok
dateext
compress
notifempty
copytruncate
size 20M
}
```

#### 2. logging.properties

Changed

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

to

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

in `conf/logging.properties` file.

Can anyone suggest me how to roll out daily logs from catalina.out?

Comment: The solutions you cite together decrease the amount of logs in `catalina.out` and rotate the file daily. Can you explain exactly what other solution are you looking for?

Comment: The solution that I'm looking is to have daily logs of catalina.out be rolled out to the respective log file so that the catalina.out file consists of the present day logs only. However, I observed that the date specific log file gets created but it does not consists of the entire catalina logs for that day. The logs keeps appending to the catalina.out file due to which its size keeps on increasing. Hope this clarifies my problem.